# What system color should be used to draw text on accent background?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to put text in a panel with accent (PhoneAccentBrush) background. PhoneForegroundBrush for text looks good in dark theme, but doesn't play well with light theme. It looks like the text always should be white regardless the theme.

What color should be used in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White is probably your best bet. (It's used for the text on live tiles to aid easier readability regardless of the tile color-which is often the accent color.)
You could also consider black.

The size of the panel and the weight & size of the text will impact appropriateness of color choice too.

Comment: This cropped up for me, too. After trying different built-in brush resources, I finally settled on white. Hardcoding a value seemed anathema to me, but it worked best for both themes.